# Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. OledbException was unhandled... did everything i saw here in stack but nothing seems to work

Tags: vb.net, ado

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
OpenConnection()
cmd.Connection = con
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [StudentInfo] ([Stud_Num], [Stud_FName], [Stud_LName], [Stud_ContactNum], [Stud_Email], [Stud_Address], [Stud_Username], [Stud_Password], [Stud_ConfirmPassword]) VALUES (" & _
                  txtStudNum.Text & ", '" & txtFname.Text & "', '" & txtLname.Text & "', '" & _
                  txtNum.Text & "', '" & txtEmail.Text & "', '" & txtAddress.Text & "' , '" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtPassword.Text & "', '" & txtConPassword.Text & "')"
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

The error was the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` I'm still a student and a noob in using vb.net so please could you tell me what I did wrong ?

Comment: If you really looked already you had to have seen the warnings against concatenating SQL and storing passwords as plaintext.  The informative part of the error message is left out in the `...` part.  Also, the user should not pick an ID, use an autoincrement PK.

Comment: thanks for answering. I only did what our professor gave us to study. the problem is within the access database. but thanks for the help I'll read the things that you told me.

Comment: no one can help you because you left out too much of the error message.  See [Ask]

Comment: The error you are seeing is a catch all. Usual cause is a minor syntax error in the SQL. Another common problem is a single quote character within the data - double up all single quotes.

Comment: I don't see an error in your command. This will fail if any of the inputs have single quotes in them: single quotes must be doubled when they occur within quotes, or how does the database know where the string really ends? Failing that, you might try, (a) displaying the text after you build the string, so you can see what the command that you're trying to send really is. And (b) including the full text of the error message in your question. Maybe if we saw the full message we'd have more of a clue what the problem is.

Comment: Oh, you might try using a parameterized query, i.e. put the values in with "@" variables and use addparam to set them. That would eliminate some potential problems.

Comment: Use parameterized queries is indeed the better way to go, but to attempt to answer your question, is there a reason why the first parameter is not surrounded by single quotes?